# Compiling C Libraries to be linked in C++ builds... do you need to specify C++ standards?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, standards

This might be a stupid question, but I'm not 100% sure and can't find a good answer via googling, so I thought I should ask it.

I'm building a few C libraries on a new compiler that will be linked with C++ code. I'm compiling the libraries from scratch because I'm moving up compiler versions from gcc4.x to gcc5.x, which requires me to recompile all of my C++ libraries with -std=gnu++14 (the language standard I'm targeting). My question is, do I need to add -std=gnu++14 to my CFLAG values when compiling to C libraries? I don't *think* I do, but want to confirm that I won't run into major issues down the road.

Thanks.

Comment: No recompile, C has an application binary interface (ABI)

Comment: some good info here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When you are compiling C code with a C compiler, you can specify the version of the C language you are using, but you cannot specify the C++ language version.  It would not make sense to specify a C++ language version because there is no sensible effect that such a setting could have.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was assuming, but needed the affirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ compiler will mangle symbol names, you'll want to surround C code with a `extern C {` block. The common idiom is like so.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* My C symbols, functions, etc */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: is this really necessary? can he just make the code in *.c file?

Comment: @Nick: It would be good to read about the difference between headers and libraries (i.e. object files).

Comment: @Nick it's *absolutely necessary* the file extension does not really matter, but gcc will try to compile based on it, but you can override that.

Comment: I've gotten in this fight before.. my personal preference is to not include any `C++`-compatibility stuff in my `C` code. Makes more sense to me to have a distinct separation between the two and keep them modularized. If `C++` wants to call `C` code, then it can go to the `extern "C" {...}` trouble. But I suppose the end results are the same so who cares.

Comment: @self _"it's absolutely necessary the file extension does not really matter"_ This statement isn't really consistent with your answer then. You probably should add this in 1st place to it.

Comment: This is tangentially related, but you did not answer the user's question.

Comment: yano: Your preference seems really bad to me.  It is very valuable to developers if they can just take working C code, paste it into a C++ program, and have it keep working.  That is only possible because header files for C libraries include bits of code like what was posted in this answer.  You seem to be valuing tidiness of header files over the user experience.